# d3 + svg + draw many charts from different files + iteratively

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, d3.js, svg

This is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ygmkvreb/1/), which I am building with from this [example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304)

What I want to do is be able to draw many charts built by different files.

So I was thinking I would have a variable array with the files and then a for loop, fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ygmkvreb/7/). e.g.

The fiddle works but it is only drawing one chart. I think this has something to do with the following code

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```

I think I need an svg, svg1 ...svgN for every chart, and then I need to append to each svg, svg1 ...svgN wheras currently I am appending to the same svg on each iteration.

```
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
```

**Can someone help me correct my ways, or point in the right direction?** I probably need a simpler example to get the concept accross.

**EDIT1** [here](http://www.d3noob.org/2013/07/arranging-more-than-one-d3js-graph-on.html) and [here](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/5987480) are other examples but it reuses code for chart1 and chart2. I want to reduce the code used using a for loop or something to that effect.

**EDIT2** I can't seem to do someting like this, finding the `id` I want and appending to that:

```
  svg("#id"+i).append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);
```

**EDIT4** I wonder is this an approach I should take?

```
arr=["data.csv","data2.csv"];

for(i=0;i<2;i++){       
//d3.csv takes a file path and a callback function                                          
d3.csv(arr[i], createChart);
//console.log("i:",i)
}

function createChart(data){
    console.log("test:",data)

    //draw chart with data
}
```

Comment: i was thinking about that too nice question, hope someone can answer this.